# SQL: return rows with only the earliest date for each id but only if it satisfies condition

Tags: sql, date, nested

I would like to get list of unique id that have 'condition=1' before 'condition=2'.

| id | date | condition1 | condition2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022/02 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022/04 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022/05 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021/09 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022/01 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2022/02 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2022/05 | 0 | 1 |

In this case it would be 1 and 3.

`SELECT id, MIN(date) FROM TABLE GROUP BY id`

I know that i can do something like this to get first dates for id but i just cant figure out what to do for my problem

Comment: Could you please tag your DBMS?

Answer (score 2):

We can `GROUP BY` id and build two conditional `MIN` dates using `CASE WHEN`.

In the `HAVING` clause we say that the minimum date with condition 1 must appear before the minimum date with condition 2.

```
SELECT id
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(CASE WHEN condition1 = 1 THEN date END) < 
MIN(CASE WHEN condition2 = 1 THEN date END)
ORDER BY id;
```

Try out here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x0nAnOsM)

Comment: Ok wow, that's a great way to do it and I'm jealous

Comment: Thanks a lot! So if I have several conditions then I just add ‘AND’  and go over all additional cases all there is some more elegant way?

Comment: This depends on the conditions you want to apply. It could be necessary to add a where clause or they can just be added to the having clause with "AND" or "OR". Maybe you want to open another question listing all your conditions if you wish further assistance?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id
FROM
  (SELECT id, MIN(date)
  FROM TheTable
  WHERE Condition1 = 1
  GROUP BY Id) c1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT Id, MIN(date)
  FROM TheTable
  WHERE Condition2 = 1
  GROUP BY Id) c2
ON c1.Id=C2.Id AND c1.Date < c2.Date
```